# writing a string on a boolean value from a record with getter/setter

Tags: java, boolean, getter-setter

[edit]when i run the current program and input "Bristol" it outputs

"Bristol is operated by Great Western and has false"

i need it to say "Bristol is operated by Great Western and has no free step access"

I have to use Boolean for StepFreeAccess, when run it should output "**Bristol** is operated by **Great Western** and has **no free step access**" Need a way where the:

- s1 = setAccess(s1, false);
- s2 = setAccess(s2, true);
- s3 = setAccess(s3, true);

gets changed into String i.e true = "step free access" and false = "no step free access".

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ex8 {
public static void main (String [] args){
    records s1 = new records();
    records s2 = new records();
    records s3 = new records();

    s1 = setName(s1, "Bristol");
    s2 = setName(s2, "Reading");
    s3 = setName(s3, "York");

    s1 = setCompany(s1,"Great Western");
    s2 = setCompany(s2,"Great Western");
    s3 = setCompany(s3,"Great Eastern");

    s1 = setAccess(s1, false);
    s2 = setAccess(s2, true);
    s3 = setAccess(s3, true);

    Scanner new1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What station do you need to know about?");
    String answer = new1.nextLine();

    if (answer.equals("Bristol")) {
        System.out.println(s1.station +" is operated by "+ s1.operatingCompany +" and has "+s1.stepFreeAccess);
    }

    else if(answer.equals("Reading")) {
        System.out.println(s2.station +" is operated by "+ s2.operatingCompany +" and has "+s2.stepFreeAccess);
    }

    else if(answer.equals("York")) {
        System.out.println(s3.station +" is operated by "+ s3.operatingCompany +" and has "+s3.stepFreeAccess);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("I do not know that Station.");
    }
}

// Getter methods   
public static String getName (records s){
    return s.station;
}

public static String getComapny (records s){
    return s.operatingCompany;
}

public static Boolean getAccess (records s) {
    return s.stepFreeAccess;
}
// Setter methods 
public static records setName (records s, String station){
    s.station = station;
    return s;
}

public static records setCompany (records s, String company){
    s.operatingCompany = company;
    return s;
}

public static records setAccess(records s, Boolean access) {
    s.stepFreeAccess = access;
    return s;
}
}



public class records {
String station;
String operatingCompany;
Boolean stepFreeAccess;
}
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: when i run the current program and input "Bristol" it outputs "Bristol is operated by Great Western and has false" i need it to say "Bristol is operated by Great Western and has no free step access". need to change the boolean false into "no free step access" somehow i've been trying for a while now and have found no success

Comment: check my answer to your first case.

Answer (score 2):

In General:

Getters/Setters should be in a class with corisponding fields. For example the getAcces() method should be part of the class records

```
public boolean getAcces(){
   return this.stepFreeAccess 
}

public void setAcces(acces){
    this.stepFreeAcces = access;
}
```

In your case I would recomend to write a constructor for records. The constructor should need Station, OperatingCompany and StepFreeAccess. In the constructor you give the corisponding fields their value.

To then solve your problem you could now set the getter from acces to deliver the needed String.

For example:

```
public String getAccess(){
    if(this.access){
        return *return String for true here*
    }else{
        return *return String for false here*
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.

Comment: @mypetlion When the method getAccess() in the records class returns the corrisponding String for the boolean stepFreeAccess you can call getAcces() in your Output.

Answer (score 0):

For **Bristol** case, you can try:

```
if (answer.equals("Bristol")) {
    String aux = "";

    if (s1.stepFreeAccess) aux = "step free access";
    else aux = "no step free access"; 

    System.out.println(s1.station +" is operated by "+ s1.operatingCompany +" and has "+aux);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but i have specific requirements to use records and for the "step free access" to be a boolean so in my case it dosen't work. It gets the result i want just not in a they way i need i to be

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that you need.